# Adding support library repository to Android Studio project?

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I've been having some of the same issues that others have had importing the Support Library to my Android Studio libraries.

When running:

> ./gradlew clean

I get:

> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0.

Below is my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 17
    }
}
```

I have downloaded the support repository from the SDK.
We don't still need to setup a different library project containing just the support library?

Comment: I'm successful using `buildToolsVersion '18.0.1'`. Download it from SDK first.

Comment: I upgraded to buildToolsVersion "18.0.1" but still have the same issue.

Comment: Try `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'`.